# Modifying recursive query to limit results to first matching node of a tree

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I have this SQL output from the acts_as_ordered_tree gem:

```
SELECT "component_instances".* 
FROM "component_instances" 
INNER JOIN (
   WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS ( 
      SELECT id, parent_id, ARRAY[position] AS _positions
      FROM "component_instances"
      WHERE "component_instances"."id" = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT alias1.id, alias1.parent_id, _positions || alias1.position
      FROM descendants 
      INNER JOIN "component_instances" alias1 
              ON alias1.parent_id = descendants.id
   ) 
   SELECT * FROM descendants
) AS descendants 
ON descendants.id = component_instances.id 
WHERE ("component_instances"."id" != 1) 
  AND (component_instances.archived_at IS NOT NULL 
  AND component_instances.archive_number IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY descendants._positions ASC
```

This query is for a recycle bin, where I want to show component_instances that have been 'archived' (see the last condition at the end of the query). I don't want to show children of an archived component_instance even though they are also marked as archived because you can't logically restore these nodes unless you have restored the originally deleted parent first.

I'm having trouble getting my head around modifying this query so that it won't recurse when it encounters an archived node but will still include that node in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand the question properly,
I'll try to show my understanding using an example:

Say the table `component_instances` has the following records:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID | POSITION | ARCHIVED_AT | ARCHIVE_NUMBER |
|----|-----------|----------|-------------|----------------|
|  1 |    (null) |   (null) |      (null) |         (null) |
|  2 |         1 |   (null) |      (null) |         (null) |
|  3 |         1 |   (null) |           1 |              1 | <== archived
| 21 |         2 |   (null) |      (null) |         (null) |
| 22 |        21 |   (null) |      (null) |         (null) |
| 31 |         3 |   (null) |      (null) |         (null) | <== children of 3
| 32 |        31 |   (null) |      (null) |         (null) | <== children of 3
```

As I understand, the query is expected to retrieve the record `id=3` even though it is "archived",

but must skip records `id=31` and `id=32` because there are children of "archived" record `id=3`.

If my understanding is correct, then append an additional column `archived_at` to the SELECT clause,

and check whether `archived_at` of the parent record is nul or not null after the join:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS ( 
      SELECT id, parent_id, ARRAY[position] AS _positions,
             /* new column */
             archived_at
      FROM "component_instances"
      WHERE "component_instances"."id" = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT alias1.id, alias1.parent_id, _positions || alias1.position,
             /* new column */
             alias1.archived_at
      FROM descendants
      INNER JOIN "component_instances" alias1 
              ON alias1.parent_id = descendants.id
      /* new condition - the parent record is not archived */
      WHERE descendants.archived_at is null
) 
SELECT * FROM descendants
;
```

demo (see the last query in this demo) --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/033a7/6

Comment: Thanks for that, it's nice and succinct, and works perfectly! You left off the last part of my original query so that your query also returns parents above the deleted parents are returned too. The intent of my query was to only return the deleted (archived) notes minus their children. Just adding the rest of the query back to the end fixes this. Did you want to update your answer to show this?